# Protecting twitter keys on Android

Tags: android, facebook, security, authentication, twitter

When adding twitter authentication to my android app, going to [Twitter dev](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/twitter), I was flabbergasted at finding that I have to initialize Twitter's `Fabric` like this:

```
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.Twitter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig;
...

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = 
                new TwitterAuthConfig("consumerKey",
                                     "consumerSecret");
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
}
```

They are **officialy recommending** that I put both **API Key** and **API Secret** in my app as plaintext. Even in this **[official sample](https://github.com/twitterdev/cannonball-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/fabric/samples/cannonball/App.java#L97)**, the keys are stored in `BuildConfig`.

I am using **Proguard** but even then, I cannot guarantee that a determined hacker wouldn't be able to exploit my *API Secret*. Do established apps like *Quora* also expose these keys?

**Can somebody post an example for overcoming this vulnerability, or give a convincing argument as to why Twitter is doing this?**

In contrast, **Google** and **Facebook** only required me to add an **AppID**, and I had to hash my signing certificates and link the hashes to respective apps. This is levels of magnitude more secure than above.

Comment: Alex from Fabric here. Just wanted to expand on why we show this method in sample apps and some of our documentation. The examples illustrate the simplest mechanism to integrate with the kits. Every team and organization has different policies when it comes to security, so we leave the decision how to secure and where to store the keys and secrets to each developer. I definitely hear you though, and we can look into providing documentation around more secure options.

Comment: @Alexizamerican Thanks very much for replying. The twitter keys I intend to use have **write** access. It just seems to me that no matter how secure I make these strings, I am still shipping my Twitter API secret to users. I don't have any guaranteed way around this security issue, so I was wondering if there is any other way to do it. I am ok with it being a complex method. Ideally the app should never have any access to my secret.

Comment: Hello - I'm also concerned about this. Did you managed to figure out a safer way to store the key/secret pair? I'm also wondering if integrating twitter is such a good idea because this looks completely insecure.

Comment: @Simon unfortunately, no. I simply dropped Twitter authentication because of this. However, if you really need it, your best bet is dexguard, but that is paid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proguard will not obfuscate string literals. Instead you could store the secret as an encrypted string (maybe using AES) and decrypt when required. Alternatively, commercial programs such as [Stringer](https://jfxstore.com/stringer/)  or [Dexguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/) provide string obfuscation.

Comment: Yes, encrypted strings are harder to un-obfuscate (not sure if that's a word :P), but since I am putting the necessary crypto code in the app, it doesn't guarantee security. Besides, if someone develops an exploit to extract twitter keys from a pro(dex)guarded app, it will give him access to a plethora of twitter apps. It seems like too big of a security hole.

Comment: Damn. I didn't think of that. If you stored the secret as an array of characters (or ints?) and then used your own logic to reproduce the string, as long as you then 'apply' Proguard, you should be covered.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a secrets.xml file in your res/ directory and have constants with those values and reference them from your activity.